# How to conduct mesh analysis on a current source in series with a resistance?

Tags: dc, current-source, analysis

How can I do a mesh analysis of the following kind of circuit? I'd normally put up Kirchoff's voltage laws for each of the two loops. If the current source wasn't in series with a resistance, I'd write down the voltage law for the complete sling (R 3-4-6-9-8) and the relation between the partial circuits, but in this case, I don't know how to handle the current source.

[image]

How can I conduct a mesh analysis?

Comment: Solved it! But I can't delete my question =/

Comment: Don't delete your question.  Instead, answer it and accept the answer.  Maybe you'll help out the next guy.

Comment: It will help you earn points too.

Comment: @markrages: Ok, I tried to before, but there was a limit before I could answer my own question. Will try again later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write down Kirchoff's voltage law for the combined loop. That is, disregard the current source and any elements in series with it, since they're not part of the loop.

The relation between the two partial currents is then:

$$I_d - I_u = I_2$$

where \$I_d\$ is the clockwise current in the lower mesh, and \$I_u\$ is the clockwise current in the upper mesh.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer, when you can. I think that you need to wait a day or two, but don't forget that!